# How to implement stdarg in C

Tags: c, header-files

For curiosity, I'm looking to write minimal replacements for some of the functions in the standard C library. So far, I have finished `printf()`, `strlen()`, `strcpy()`, `memcpy()`, `memset()`, etc... but when I try to use the printf function, I don't know how to implement `stdarg.h`! What is a way that I could do that?

Does it use macros or actual functions?

I am using `gcc` OR `clang` on 32-bit x86, if it helps to make this any easier to answer.

Comment: Why not just look into the **header** provided by your prefered compiler? Note that this is implementation-specific. Any comprehensive answer would be too broad. Please be more specific.

Comment: @Olaf I've been looking in the source code of both gcc, clang and glibc for 2 hours, and I couldn't find one that even remotely looks like an implementation.

Comment: Please read the first sentence of my comment carefully again. Actually, read the whole comment.

Comment: I think reimplementing functions expected only from a hosted environment, as you’ve been doing so far, is a good exercise; however, implementing functionality from headers that are supposed to be available even in a freestanding environment, namely `float.h`, `iso646.h`, `limits.h`, **`stdarg.h`**, `stdbool.h`, `stddef.h`, and `stdint.h`, is not such a great exercise, as implementations of those are more likely to rely on compiler- or architecture-specific behavior and may not be portable.

Comment: @Olaf The header provided by gcc says something useless like "typedef __builtin_va_list va_list" which doesn't tell me anything about what that does. However, I agree with you that such an answer might be too broad, so I will attempt to make the question more specific.

Comment: In particular, `stdarg.h` is probably one of the harder things to decide to reimplement, rivaled only by `setjmp.h`. Both of these need to know low-level things about both the compiler, the architecture, and the rest of the implementation, and depending on the architecture and other factors, may need to be implemented at least partially in assembly rather than pure C.

Comment: So because this kind of function is very complicated to implement, I'm probably just better off using libgcc, and my other main point when I started to do this was to make programs smaller. libgcc does not increase the size that much anyway...

Comment: I like he is learning in this manner. Next step could be to improve those standard functions as many old c-standard functions are rather badly designed - compared to todays standards and best practices. If you really want to use the results of your works, I would even recommend to start with this improvement step right away and skip the re-implementing.

Comment: @icktoofay: Is is particularily a matter of the procedure call standard and the ABI of the architecture. Good knowledege about the CPU, its stack, etc. is certainly also required.

Comment: @AnonymousShadow: Normally only the functions actually used are linked statically. And for dynamic linking, the code normally is shared between all processes using it.

Comment: @BitTickler: If you refer to the interfaces, these are specified by the C standard. There is little use in changing these if you want to replace the stdlib. And the implementaions depend on the library itself. I think newlib and glibc are actually not _that_ bad considering the standard functions.

Comment: @AnonymousShadow: Perhaps you have a look at some cross-compiler toolchains to get an idea. However, I might well be you are lacking the required knowledge - no offfence! So perhaps you first step back and have a look at CPU, hardware-stack and calling standards. ARM Cortex-M may be a good start: the CPU is quite simple (much simpler than x86 and the documents are freely available. Of course this will take some time.

Comment: @AnonymousShadow : since you implemented printf() and friends (> 100K SOURCE in Apache, BTW), you already solved the problem. Without knowing it.

Comment: @Olaf I mostly refer to terrible functions such as ``realloc() etc.`` and functions which take array parameters without capacity information. To get the idea, inspect the ``_s`` versions of the classics. If he requires smaller footprint (which he claims), he most likely works with highly proprietary embedded systems code and is less prone to suffer from creating his own standard library as he most likely will not have to incorporate random code written independently for other purposes.

Comment: @BitTickler: What is the problem with the interface of `realloc`? And as I wrote, that is mandated by the standard; there is little use in changing it if you want to use many other libraries. Unless you use a freestandanding implementation/environment and only use your own libraries, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On 32-bit x86 with the cdecl calling convention, parameters are passed on the stack:

```
^ higher addresses (lower on the stack)
|
| caller local variables
| ...
| argument 3
| argument 2
| argument 1
| return address
| saved EBP (usually)
| callee local variables
|
v lower addresses (higher on the stack)
```

You can implement `va_list` as a pointer. `va_start` can take the address of the argument passed to it and add the size of that argument to move to the next argument. `va_arg` can access the pointer and bump it to the next argument. `va_copy` can just copy the pointer value. `va_end` doesn’t need to do anything.

If, on the other hand, you’re not using cdecl (maybe you’re using fastcall), you’re not 32-bit, you’re not x86, this won’t work; you might need to muck with registers rather than just pointer values. And even still it’s not guaranteed to work, since you’re relying on undefined behavior; as as example of only one potential problem, inlining could ruin everything. And that’s why the header file just `typedef`s it to a compiler built-in—implementing this in C is hopeless, you need compiler support. And don’t even get me started on implementing `setjmp` and `longjmp`…

Comment: Because this is practically impossible to implement "properly" without writing a compiler (and I don't know how), is the best solution just to link with libgcc?

Comment: @AnonymousShadow: First try linking without including `libgcc`; since `va_*` are macros that refer to built-ins, it might not add any external function references, and hence you might not need to link anything extra in at all. That said, if you get undefined symbol errors for symbols that `libgcc` defines, yeah, I guess you’d need to link that in.

Comment: This answer is wrong; it assumes ancient compiler technology where the address of argument objects will actually be the address they were (or would have been) passed on the stack. There's no reason this need be the case. Even on archs like i386 where the arguments to external functions are passed on the stack, the compiler is completely free to move them to separate local storage and have `&` yield a pointer to that new storage. It's also free to perform inlining/LTO in which case the arguments might never live on the stack at all.

Comment: @R..: I understand, which is why I point out that it is entirely unreliable, even if all the preconditions are met, in the last paragraph.

Comment: Fair enough. FYI, despite calling it "wrong", I'm not the one who downvoted your answer.

Comment: "... relying on undefined behavior ..." Not undefined, but implementation defined. However, you are missing alignment issues. The answer would be ok if stated that it is just a simplified example to get the idea. You cannot rely on something undefined. Mentioning `inline` is a good point. However, the compiler is free to ignore `inline`, so can it for variadic functions.

Comment: @Olaf: No. The pointer addition in these kinds of macros is explicitly undefined, not implementation-defined. Being undefined does not preclude the possibility of a particular implementation choosing to define a behavior as an extension to the language, but *implementation-defined behavior* has a very specific meaning: that the C standard *requires* an implementation to choose *and document* a particular behavior. Undefined behavior on the other hand means the standard places no constraints on the behavior of the program.

Comment: In case you need a reference for the behavior being undefined, in C11 it's 6.5.6 Additive operators, paragraph 8.

Comment: Have you ever programmed OS-code? There are things you have to do which are - strictily speaking - undefined by the standard, yet still correctly working. And the processing of `stdargs` is clearly left to the implementation by the standard. If that defines a certain layout, you **can** do it. But you should never do this in application code beyond low-level hardware-tight functions (bare-metal) or OS (others) and implementation-specific libraries.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to implement `stdarg.h` macros in C; you need compiler builtins like `__builtin_va_arg`, etc. which GCC and compatible compilers provide, or the equivalent for your compiler.

Even if you know the argument passing convention for the particular target you're working with (like i386 in icktoofay's answer), there is no way in C to get access to this memory. Simply performing pointer arithmetic on the address passed to `va_start` is not valid; it results in undefined behavior. But even if C did allow that arithmetic, there's no guarantee that the address of the last named argument actually corresponds to the place it was passed on the stack as part of the calling convention; the compiler could have chosen to move it to a different location in its stack frame (perhaps for the sake of obtaining additional alignment or data locality).

Comment: That depends on the PCS/ABI of the architecture. The macros can very well care about alignment, as they know the types. Early implementations actually **did** use macros for this. I had these on the 68000, for example (IIRC, this was gcc 1.something, but not sure). And reordering would mess up calls between different compilation units, at least.

Comment: @Olaf: It's independent of ABI. Even if you know that args are *passed* the the stack, you do not know that `&argN` is the address of the stack slot it was passed on. Within the function body, `argN` is just a normal automatic-storage object. The compiler is free to position it wherever it wants (as long as it copies the original value from wherever the calling convention put it) and this is purely an *internal* consideration of how the function was compiled, not ABI.

Comment: Of course it's true that some historical compilers were so primitive that `&argN` was always the stack slot it was passed on, or that they intentionally chose to forgo optimizations to facilitate legacy `stdarg.h` implementations. But in that case, it worked only because of assumptions about the non-ABI-relevant behavior of the compiler, not just by knowing the ABI.

Comment: Huh? The standard implementations increment the pointer just by the size of the current argument, align it and have the address of the next entry. This is normally part of the PCS and ABI. See the current ARM-standard (AAPCS, this includes the basic C/C++ ABI). And, no, the compiler is not free, unless it can proof the functions is not called from elsewhere. This can only work for `static`.

Comment: As `stdarg.h` is part of the implementation, i.e. the compiler, so it certainly has to know what the compiler does (it has to conform to the ABI ...). Note that this clearly assumes the compiler does not inline such functions, but this can also be specified in the ABI.

Comment: You're missing the point. I did not claim the compiler can modify the calling convention, just the layout of automatic objects within its own call frame. The latter is NOT governed by ABI.

Comment: "The latter is NOT governed by ABI" Someone should tell ARM.

Comment: Of course if a compiler provides a `stdarg.h`, it has to meet the assumptions of its own `stdarg.h`, which may place constraints on what the compiler can do. This is why good compilers instead use something like `__builtin_va_arg`: so they don't impose any constraints on themselves. However OP's question was about writing a `stdarg.h` yourself. That is something that you fundamentally cannot do just by knowing the ABI. You also need additional assumptions about what the compiler will and won't do *within a function*.

Comment: @Olaf: No, ARM has it perfectly right. You're just misunderstanding what you're talking about.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm listening myself very carefully. But that is leading nowhere.

Answer (score 3):

There's an implementation in the CALC source code posted to [comp.sources.unix](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.sources.unix/7_uQ8aKdDx0/discussion) in 1992.

This is from a shar archive, so ignore the `X`s.

```
X * Copyright (c) 1992 David I. Bell
X * Permission is granted to use, distribute, or modify this source,
X * provided that this copyright notice remains intact.

X/*
X * SIMULATE_STDARG
X *
X * WARNING: This type of stdarg makes assumptions about the stack
X *             that may not be true on your system.  You may want to
X *            define STDARG (if using ANSI C) or VARARGS.
X */
X
Xtypedef char *va_list;
X#define va_start(ap,parmn) (void)((ap) = (char*)(&(parmn) + 1))
X#define va_end(ap) (void)((ap) = 0)
X#define va_arg(ap, type) \
X    (((type*)((ap) = ((ap) + sizeof(type))))[-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see examples of how to implement the va macros [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/include/stdarg.h.htm). This header is used in VC++ and there are different implementations for each  processor architecture. The macros don't seem to be specific to the Microsoft  compiler. In both GCC and Clang the va macros refer to compiler built-in functions.