# Disable passing arguments to functions via registers (gcc, clang)

Tags: gcc, clang++

for University we need to implement our own va_start and va_arg (without using libraries) for variable argument lists.

This isn't really a problem, but gcc and clang are giving us a hard time.

They are optimizing the code so that the parameter are passed through registers and not on the stack, which makes our task impossible.

I already tried to use optimization -O0 but even then they seem to pass them in registers.

Is there a way to disable that feature?

best wishes
Leo

**Edit:**
We are using 64-bit machines only

**Edit2:**
I found this site:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_17.html
It describes macros which define if a parameter is passed on the stack or not.
Could I use these marcos somehow to tell gcc to pass all parameters on the stack?

I played around with them but sadly did not archive anything...

Comment: How parameters are passed is actually dictated by calling conventions, so you might have to change those. They are part of the internal ABI, though, so you would need to tell the compiler accordingly. What is your architecture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement stdarg in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291808/how-to-implement-stdarg-in-c)

Comment: I looked for the calling conventions and only found something for 32-Bit for now.
@cadaniluk answer fits for 32-Bit only

Comment: Yeah no, x86-64 (I assume that's your arch then) added a bunch of registers, so using registers for passing arguments became a lot more comfy with x86-64. x86 has, in comparison with other archs such as ARM, only few registers, so the stack was the usual means for passing stuff around. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32292315/3494013) answer to the duplicate question seems worth reading.

Comment: Why not compile for `-m32`?

Comment: @cadaniluk Yeah I read that which pretty much says it is impossible, I'm still wondering if someone has an idea

Comment: @a3f No it has to be compiled with -m64 because we are building it for an already quite complex selfwritten compiler which depends on 64-bit

Comment: If it's part of a compiler project, why not have the compiler support variable-length arguments? If you own the compiler, you can impose whatever calling convention you want.

Comment: The compiler does not use any libraries, so if the compiler has a printf function itself then it uses our own va_start and va_arg.
The compiler needs to be compiled by gcc and clang and because of the optimization the va_start and va_arg won't work anymore.
Everything compiled by the compiler works just fine...

Comment: @LDK What does it matter what the compiler is compiled with? Are you trying to mix code compiled by gcc/clang and code compiled by your own compiler? (If so, why?)

Comment: For any questions, this is the project I'm talking about:
https://github.com/cksystemsteaching/selfie
I'm not in charge to define the compiler which compiles the project. For now it is gcc and clang and that is why I have the question, because I cannot access the parameters which I need to have on the stack.

Comment: Argument passing depend on the ABI: it doesn't depend on the compiler, so we need the architecture *and* the operating system to be specified in the question

Comment: @YannDroneaud sorry for the delay, It is x86_64 but it would need to work on Windows, Mac and Linux

Comment: @LDK calling convention for x86_64 on Windows and Linux are differents: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions, if your compiler doesn't follow them you won't be able to call libraries functions